# How can I get the child node based on clickevent

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a have several `divs` on a page called `parent_container` inside it I have a `heading`, `image` and a `button`

how can I get the value for the specific `heading` of the container it was clicked from?

```
<div class="parent_container">
   <img class="news_image" src="/" />
    <h1 class="product_title">title 1</h1>
    <a class="cta-btn" href="#">button1</a>
</div>

<div class="parent_container">
    <img class="news_image" src="/" />
     <h1 class="news_title">title 2</h1>
     <a class="cta-btn" href="#">button2</a>
</div>
```

```js
//getting the elements
var update_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName( 'cta-btn' ),
    parentElement  = document.getElementsByClassName( 'parent_container' ),
    itemTitle      = document.getElementsByClassName( 'news_title' );

//trying to get the title from the div it was clicked in
var getTitle = function( evt ) {
    var title = this.itemTitle;

    console.log( title ); //undefined
}

//setting up a event listener on all the buttons on the page 
for( var i=0;i<update_buttons.length;i++ ){
    update_buttons[i].addEventListener('click', getTitle);
}
```

Comment: So you want the text inside the `h1` tag?

Comment: yes, would like to get the value of the nested `h1` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you got a typo: `console.log(title)`. And here is what you need to do, get the parent, then the child for the header:

```
var title = this.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML;
console.log( title );
```

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a8nmsh9y/)**

*Note* this assumes that you have the same structure for the `<div class="parent_container">` item, such that the title is the second item.

**Edit**

If the structure is changed you can select the item with `querySelector('h1')`:

```
var title = this.parentNode.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
console.log( title );
```

As **@JoshCrozier** proposed you can use `.querySelector('h1[class*="title"]')` which means it selects some class with the word "title" in it. So `product_title`, `news_title`, `something_title` will work. That way you can have other `<h1>` elements in the `<div>` as well if you happen to want to add them (you just have to make sure they don't have a class with the word "title" in those).

Comment: is there is a way to reference the title by its class name or tag name an not its position? because sometimes the html gets moved around

Comment: Certainly, use `var title = this.parentNode.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;`.

Comment: I like this because I don't want to be worried about the javascript if for some reason I decide to change the markup..although I'd still think hooking in to the `H1` is still a bit risky.

Comment: @Grundizer Which is why you should over-qualify the selector and add the class too... as I did in my answer. Also, avoid using `.innerHTML` and use `textContent`/`innerText` when possible.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Is correct, I simply did it for the `h1` tag simply because that is what was asked for. But it would be a good idea to do `h1.product_title` instead. That being said you need to change your HTML to have that work correctly. Such that all `parent_container` need that class. For example it would not work for the title with the class `news_title`.

Comment: @Grundizer Take a look at the attribute sample I provided. If you attach that attribute to every `H1` a markup change shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Get the clicked element using `evt.toElement` (In this case, `this` works too, though).

From there, get the parent node, and then select the child `h1` element.

Access the text using [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent):

```
var getTitle = function (evt) {
    var el = evt.toElement, // or this
        parent = el.parentNode,
        header = parent.querySelector('h1[class*="title"]'),
        headerText = header.textContent;

    console.log(headerText);
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sdqz5jd4/)

..and if you prefer not to cache variables:

```
evt.toElement.parentNode.querySelector('h1[class*="title"]').textContent;
```

```js
//getting the elements
var update_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('cta-btn'),
    parentElement = document.getElementsByClassName('parent_container'),
    itemTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('news_title');

//trying to get the title from the div it was clicked in
var getTitle = function (evt) {
    var el = evt.toElement,
        parent = el.parentNode,
        header = parent.querySelector('h1[class*="title"]'),
        headerText = header.textContent;
    
    console.log(headerText);
}

//setting up a event listener on all the buttons on the page 
for (var i = 0; i < update_buttons.length; i++) {
    update_buttons[i].addEventListener('click', getTitle);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_container">
   <img class="news_image" src="/" />
    <h1 class="product_title">title 1</h1>
    <a class="cta-btn" href="#">button1</a>
</div>

<div class="parent_container">
    <img class="news_image" src="/" />
     <h1 class="news_title">title 2</h1>
     <a class="cta-btn" href="#">button2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem here is the different classes used. So `h1.product_title` wouldn't work on the `second container`.

Comment: @Mouser Ahhh. Good point. I didn't realize the classes were different.

Comment: Yes that is a nice one. I like those querySelectors. Made life a lot easier. I used to do those things with Xpath, but these are far better.

Comment: That's a nifty solution. As long as `title` is somewhere in there (which to the looks of it is likely) that will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with the least steps. It seams that your title is always the previous element of the button.

Use:

```
 var getTitle = function( evt ) {
     var title = this.previousElementSibling.textContent || this.previousElementSibling.innerText;

    console.log( title ); //undefined

  }
```

To be sure that you always return the correct element you need a bit more than the sample above. Why am I saying this. If you (or someone else) edits the html the solution above could break. A better solution is to give the `title element` a class name or better an attribute that is only used for those titles. Take a look at this solution:

```
 <div class="parent_container">
      <img class="news_image" src="/" />
      <h1 title-element class="news_title">title 2</h1>
      <a class="cta-btn" href="#">button2</a>
 </div>
```

```js
 var getTitle = function( evt ) {
     var title = this.parentElement.querySelector("h1[title-element]");

    return title.textContent || title.innerText;

  }
```

The above answer makes it less likely that your function breaks when the html gets updated in the future.

PS. The `|| element.innerText` is a fall back for older browsers (read IE) that don't support textContent.

Comment: In many browsers, the *previousSibling* will be a *textNode* that doesn't have an *innerHTML* property.

Comment: @RobG true. Thanks. Updated it with `previousElementSibling`

Comment: Those aren't functions

Comment: Google what, that they exist or that they are functions?

Comment: @Musa My humble excuses. It was too late at night when I wrote that comment in retrospect. :-) You are absolutely right. There're properties.